# Lexicographic comparison of two numpy ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I couldn't find a straightforward way to compare two (multidimensional in my case) arrays the in a lexicographic  way.

Ie.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [4,0,1,6]
```

For `a < b` I want to get `true` where I get `[true, false, false, true]`
For `a > b` I want to get `false` where I get `[false, true, true, false]`

Comment: How is the final true/false derived?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: [Lexicographic comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), the same way lists and tuples are compared.

Comment: lexicographically. ie. if the first number is different, the array with the bigger wins. if they are the same the comparison goes to the 2. etc

Comment: By the way, `ndarray.sort` doesn't sort lexicographically.

Comment: @user2357112 I thought it did. I'll edit the question once i figure out.

Comment: @user2357112 just tried, to me it really looks like it does...

Comment: @user2357112 oh yes, didn't know it was that. However `a < b` and `a > b` will return the respective values if they were lists. Will that not do?

Comment: @AdamToth: [Here's an example that's pretty obviously not lexicographic.](http://ideone.com/V3aEvW)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: They're arrays, not lists. While we could build lists, that's a pretty expensive conversion to perform if we don't have to.

Comment: @user2357112 oh, arrays. Sheesh

Comment: @user2357112 You are right I mixed it with normal python arrays. I'm a noob.

Comment: I guess I'm writing my own function for it. Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Can you add a multi-dimensional array case with the expected output? Also, if you have implemented something, add into the question or post as answer if it solved it for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is just about finding whether `a` is `<` or `>` than `b`, then the following should work.

```
def fn(a, b):
    # finds index of the first non matching element
    idx = np.where( (a>b) != (a<b) )[0][0]

    if a[idx] < b[idx]: print "a < b" 
    if a[idx] > b[idx]: print "a > b"
```

Comment: I edited your answer to remove `== True`, which is implied (and slow to run), and to spell `^` as `!=` for clarity

Comment: Presumably, you're using `(a>b) != (a<b)` over `a != b` in order to handle `nan`s?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply with np.arange(4)[::-1] ** 2 and then sum over that axis.

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?